# Does general relativity prohibit spacetime expanding in a higher dimensional space?

Tags: general-relativity, cosmology, spacetime, space-expansion, spacetime-dimensions

Are there theoretical considerations that prohibit the 4-dimensional spacetime as described by general relativity to be situated in a higher dimensional spacetime? If not, could that explain why the universe is expanding accelerated?

Edit
To make myself clearer, I'm not asking about virtual things like Kaluza-Klein theory or Calabi-Yau manifolds. More a scenario of the 3d branes in pyrotechnical cosmologies. They are situated in a 4D space and matter (except gravitons) is confined on them, so isn't able to travel in the fourth dimension. Could our universe be a curved brane floating in a 4D space? Expanding in it while following the metric?

Comment: Higher dimensions have been tried, but not in the way you are thinking. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaluza%E2%80%93Klein_theory

Comment: Any spacetime $S$ is naturally contained in $S\times {\mathbb R}.$ If that doesn't answer your question, you need you be clearer about what properties you want your embedding to have.

Comment: @mmesser314 Im not referring to KK theory or CY manifolds. These are clearly non existent fantasies. Im referring to the same as the two 3d branes in pyrothechnical theories. Our universe being a large 6d brane (three curled up to Planckian circles to form particles) expanding in a 7d space. Or just a 3d space expanding in a negatively curved 4d space. Wouldn't this explain dark energy? You can keep particles on 3d like is done with strings  (except for gravitons necessary to curve the 4d space).

Comment: @WillO So it can be done? Or is the case?

Comment: @Felicia Thanks for that clarification. It should be edited into the question body rather than only in a comment.

Comment: @J.G. ill edit! Gotta walk the dog first... She's jumping me! :)

Comment: Extra time dimensions cause problems with stability of the vacuum.  Extra compact dimensions get you into the general line of KK theories and their varioius offshoots. Extra non-compact dimensions would need a reason we had never noticed them.

Answer (score 2):

Cosmologies in which our universe is a brane in a higher-dimensional spacetime where (most) particles are localized on that brane are called [brane cosmologies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brane_cosmology) - our universe is "the brane", the higher-dimensional spacetime is "the bulk". A popular toy model are the [Randall-Sundrum models](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randall%E2%80%93Sundrum_model), where the graviton field is special in not being localized, but present throughout the bulk.

These models were popular for a while as potential solutions to the gravitational [hierarchy problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hierarchy_problem), because they tend to produce "natural" strengths for  gravity in most of the bulk and then engineer the situation such that at the position of our brane specifically gravity turns out to be as weak as it is.

This doesn't have anything to do with space expansion, since space expansion is just a feature of the time-dependence of the metric of our universe, regardless of whether or not you embed it as a brane in some higher-dimensional surroundings.